# mootools - Middle click

Tags: mootools

How do I detect if there was a middle click in mootools 1.4.5?

I know this can be done in regular JS, but I can't get it to work in mootools.

```
$('someLink').addEvent('click', function(e){
     if(e.button == 1){ // <-- .button doesn't exist in mootools. .which doesn't either
          e.stop();
          // Does some things
     }          
});
```

Comment: If you pass `obj` in your function you can get it by `event.which`. Cannot explain why, I would love to hear some expert explaining/answering this. Maybe Dimitar or someone else will check this soon... Anyway: check here, and look at console. (http://jsfiddle.net/RDc2Z/)

Comment: There seems to be an error in that example; `event` is not even defined. After fixing the error, `.which` and `.button` are still undefined. EDIT: Ah, it works in Chrome, but not in FF.

Comment: There is no error in the example, did you check the console? You can check this one with alert() instead http://jsfiddle.net/RDc2Z/1/

Comment: pass. two things. I don't have a middle button on my mac book. two. if you need to design UI with reliance on a middle click, you are probably doing it wrong. go with ctrl/meta/cmd click, if you must. i'd look at the Event.js code if i get spare time tomorrow and see if it can be normalised before mootools 1.5 comes out.

Comment: ```event``` or ```window.event``` is a special property in the Microsoft event accessing that contains the last event that took place . I would not rely on it without a fallback.

Comment: No reliance at all. More of a check, since I know some people, including myself, like to middle click links to open in a new tab. Doing this in the site I'm working on creates unwanted behavior so I wanted to patch that up. But thanks for the ideas. There's always another way to do things.

Comment: Sergio's solution worked only in Chrome. I made some changes so now it works in FF, Chrome, and IE. Not entirely sure why this works. Isn't `.addEvent` supposed to be the same as `.addEventListener`? [(jsfiddle.net/RDc2Z/2/)](http://jsfiddle.net/RDc2Z/2/)

Comment: Good point. Maybe re-tag them to ask again.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I found a way to get button event info, but it requires `addEventListener`. My previous post has the JSFiddle. But when I try to add in event delegation and retrieval of the child's id, it gets complicated quickly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MooTools use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` depending on browser:

- `addEventListener` is used in all modern browsers and IE9+
- `attachEvent` is used in old IE < 9

But MooTools wraps event data to custom normalized object, which will have the same structure and values for all browsers. Unfortunately it doesn't handle `button` property, but it's possible to get its value.

You can get original event data from `event` property of MooTools event object, but this data might be different across the browsers. F.e. `e.button` property is not "normalized" and in old IE its value can be different from other browsers.

So your code using `addEvent` will look like following:

```
$('someLink').addEvent('mousedown', function(e){
    alert(e.event.button);       
});
```

*(Note: I'm using `mousedown` event, because of current version of Firefox browser, which doesn't fire `click` event for middle button)*

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hjsAj/

Comment: Fantastic answer! And the best part about this solution is that mootools event delegation can be used. Thank you!